# Handle null or empty collection with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have collection of company and each company has list of department and department which are filtered based on complex multilevel condition. I would like to get the department info from some other source when there is no department found in a company and then proceed with filter condition as next step. Is the below implementation best way to achieve ?

```
   public class Company{
     private List<Department> departments;
   }
```

```
       companies.stream().forEach(c -> {
            if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(c.getDepartments())){
                //handle no department 
                //Set the department after getting from different source
            }
        });
 
companies.stream()
    .filter(c -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(c.getDepartments()))
    .filter(c -> c.getDepartments().stream()
            .anyMatch(d -> condition))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That won't compile because `forEach` returns void. Are you trying to return a list of new companies that are modified versions of the existing ones? Or do you want to mutate the existing companies? Is the list `newCompanies` going to contain the same number of companies as the original list `companies`?

Comment: so why can't you chain that directly via a `map(department -> if(...) return from other source; else return departments).filter(...)`

Comment: @k314159 my bad.. fixed it .. I will add the missing grant to the company by getting from different source.. I have updated the post

Comment: @Eugene Let me try what you suggested..

Comment: @Eugene This works ..thanks a lot for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `if/else` statement in you code as suggested already. If you want your colleagues to look weird at you (who does not like that?), you could write it as:

```
companies.stream()
         .map(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.getDepartments())
                           .flatMap(dep -> dep.size() == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(dep))
                           .orElse(List.of()) // get it from another source...
        ).filter(...)
```

Comment: 1. With the current code in the question the return type is a `List` of `Company` and not `Department`. 2. `dep.size() == 0` => `dep.isEmpty` or you could even `filter` out empty collections after nullable.

Comment: `flatMap(dep -> dep.size() == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(dep))` is a very twisted way of saying `filter(dep -> !dep.isEmpty())`. On the other hand, the entire construct is an unnecessarily complicated way of saying `x -> { var dep = x.getDepartments(); if(dep == null || dep.isEmpty()) dep = …; return dep; }`…